# How to solve "itemTag cannot be resolved or is not a field"?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

In the strings.xml file, I have this:

```
<resources>
<string name="itemTag">1</string>
<string name="item2Tag">2</string>
</resources>
```

But when I go into an activity and try to access via this:

```
ib.setTag(R.string.itemTag, "itemTag");
```

It gives an error over itemTag:

```
itemTag cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it?

EDIT: Code:

```
public void changePicture(ImageButton ib) {

ib.setTag(R.string.itemTag, "itemTag");
getResources().getString(R.string.itemTag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your java `import`s, you may have imported a `R.java` different to the one in your current package.

Remove all your imports then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (Organise imports) with Eclipse and chose the correct packages to import.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a `String`, then all `R.string.itemTag` is to the compiler is an `int`. If you look in the `R` class, you will find something like the following...

```
public static class string {
    public static int itemTag = 0x30000;
}
```

Along with all the other ids that you use. What you want to do is the following...

```
getResources().getString(R.string.itemTag);
```

You should also try cleaning your project by going to Project > Clean...

Comment: The thing is, I can't access "itemTag", it pops up the error above, and are you saying to put getResources() in the activity?

Comment: Yes, `getResources()` is an `Activity` method.

Comment: Check in the path: "gen/your.app.package" do you see an "R.java" file? If not, then the project hasn't been built. If you can't build your project then you're having compiling issues.

Comment: I just cleaned the project, then it says I need to import android.R, then when I do, every single other R.id.xxx says it "cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Comment: Do you see the "R.java" file in your "gen" folder? If not there is a larger problem that I cannot see without having more details... possible a lot more details... Usually not having an "R.java" file means you have a compilation error in your "res" folder.

Comment: I don't see the file, but it was there before the clean.